# How can I have 11 ticks (groups) where each tick is an overlap (no distance) of 3 different boxes?

Tags: pgfplots, boxplot

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  boxplot/draw direction=y,
  ylabel={time (s)},
  height=8cm,
  boxplot={
      %
      % Idea: 
      %  place the 
      %  group 1 at 0,2 + 0,4 + 0,6 + 0,8
      %  group 2 at 1,2 + 1,4 + 1,6 + 1,8
      %  group 3 at 2,2 + 2,4 + 2,6 + 2,8
      %  group 3 at 3,2 + 3,4 + 3,6 + 3,8
      %  
      % in a formular:
      draw position={1/5 + floor(\plotnumofactualtype/4) + 1/5*mod(\plotnumofactualtype,4)},
      %
      % that means the box extend must be at most 0.2 :
      box extend=0.15,
  },
  % ... it also means that 1 unit in x controls the width:
  x=3cm,
  % ... and it means that we should describe intervals:
  xtick={0,1,2,...,50},
  x tick label as interval,
  xticklabels={%
      {Data set 1\\{\tiny off/on}},%
      {Data set 2\\{\tiny off/on}},%
      {Data set 3\\{\tiny off/on}},%
      {Data set 4\\{\tiny off/on}},%
  },
  x tick label style={
      text width=2.5cm,
      align=center
  },
  cycle list={{red},{blue},{green},{purple}},
]

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
60\\
516\\
710\\
503\\
1253\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
759\\
419\\
309\\
883\\
299\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
516\\
480\\
1356\\
200\\
736\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
684\\
340\\
700\\
325\\
377\\
};



\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
60\\
516\\
710\\
503\\
1253\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
759\\
419\\
309\\
883\\
299\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
516\\
480\\
1356\\
200\\
736\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
684\\
340\\
700\\
325\\
377\\
};



\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
60\\
516\\
710\\
503\\
1253\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
759\\
419\\
309\\
883\\
299\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
516\\
480\\
1356\\
200\\
736\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
684\\
340\\
700\\
325\\
377\\
};



\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
60\\
516\\
710\\
503\\
1253\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
759\\
419\\
309\\
883\\
299\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
516\\
480\\
1356\\
200\\
736\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
684\\
340\\
700\\
325\\
377\\
};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). As it it, your LaTeX code is incomplete and doesn't compile.

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake, and I fixed the code.

Comment: You have 11 (x-)ticks! For each tick, there are three boxes! The three boxes overlap! So you did it!?

Comment: I think I understand now - your picture is not the output of your code as normal, but an example of what you want to achieve. Your code has 16 dataset, so I expect that it is not really possible/relevant that it is 11 and 3

Answer (score 2):

Your title and picture is somewhat misleading, but I think this is what you are looking for:

As you already have `draw position` in your code, I just changed that

**Edit:** I also changed `box extend` and add a transparent fill style.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  boxplot/draw direction=y,
  ylabel={time (s)},
  height=8cm,
  boxplot={
      %
      % Idea: 
      %  place the 
      %  group 1 at 0,2 + 0,4 + 0,6 + 0,8
      %  group 2 at 1,2 + 1,4 + 1,6 + 1,8
      %  group 3 at 2,2 + 2,4 + 2,6 + 2,8
      %  group 3 at 3,2 + 3,4 + 3,6 + 3,8
      %  
      % in a formular:
      draw position={floor(\plotnumofactualtype/4)+1/2},
      %
      % that means the box extend must be at most 0.2 :
      box extend={0.15*((5-mod(\plotnumofactualtype,4)))},
  },
  % ... it also means that 1 unit in x controls the width:
  x=3cm,
  % ... and it means that we should describe intervals:
  xtick={0,1,2,...,50},
  x tick label as interval,
  xticklabels={%
      {Data set 1\\{\tiny off/on}},%
      {Data set 2\\{\tiny off/on}},%
      {Data set 3\\{\tiny off/on}},%
      {Data set 4\\{\tiny off/on}},%
  },
  x tick label style={
      text width=2.5cm,
      align=center
  },
  cycle list={{red},{blue},{green},{purple}},
 enlarge x limits=0.2,
 every axis plot/.append style={fill,fill opacity=0.1}
 ]

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
60\\
516\\
710\\
503\\
1253\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
759\\
419\\
309\\
883\\
299\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
516\\
480\\
1356\\
200\\
736\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
684\\
340\\
700\\
325\\
377\\
};



\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
60\\
516\\
710\\
503\\
1253\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
759\\
419\\
309\\
883\\
299\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
516\\
480\\
1356\\
200\\
736\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
684\\
340\\
700\\
325\\
377\\
};



\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
60\\
516\\
710\\
503\\
1253\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
759\\
419\\
309\\
883\\
299\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
516\\
480\\
1356\\
200\\
736\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
684\\
340\\
700\\
325\\
377\\
};



\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
60\\
516\\
710\\
503\\
1253\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
759\\
419\\
309\\
883\\
299\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
516\\
480\\
1356\\
200\\
736\\
};
\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
684\\
340\\
700\\
325\\
377\\
};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Boxplot with transparent overlapping boxes]

Comment: Nice, but still need to control the width of each dataset. The outer box (in blue) has a width of 1, the second 0.75, and the last 0.5 so each dataset can be more visible.

Comment: See edit for variable extend(width) and fill